# Cocos2d - Iphone scheduleUpdate update not being called

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, schedule

I have a Player class that extends CCNode, and i want to hava a method that is called every frame (update). In my init method i added the following line of code `[self scheduleUpdate];`
but my `-(void) update:(ccTime)deltaTime` method is never called why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is the player added to the main node ?? with the addchild function ? I mean if you have another class which uses a player instance, you should add the player to that class with the addchild method

Comment: thks! that was it.. i was adding the playerSprite not the player object :(